# Unity3D trying to understand Monoscript

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to understand what does Monoscript do, according to [Unity tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/temas/best-practices/assets-objects-and-serialization#footnote-2)

> It is important to understand that a MonoBehaviour has a reference to
>   a MonoScript, and MonoScripts simply contain the information needed to
>   locate a specific script class. Neither type of Object contains the
>   executable code of script class.
>
> A MonoScript contains three strings: an assembly name, a class name,
>   and a namespace.

Does that mean, during build, for example, every c# classes inherited from MonoBehaviour will have a MonoScript pointing to a corresponding position in ***Assembly-CSharp.dll*** ?

Comment: It does not seem anything inherits from MonoScripts but seems to be a data type storing info about a type (assembly, name and namespace). I think of it as a pointer of type used in the project to easily check and locate a type. For instance, an AssetBundle doesn't contain any code, just MS. When loaded onto the app, the MS contains info to locate the executable code in the project. Then loading an AB with scripts that are not in the project will crash. Like passing a reference as parameter, you dont pass the whole object so it is lighter. But the reference knows where to find the real data.

Comment: Sorry i actually meaned inherit from monobehevior

Comment: It seems like so indeed. MonoBehaviour classes gets their MonoScript object so Unity can find them in the assembly. Are you asking out of curiosity or you have a specific issue you think you could solve by knowing more about it?

Comment: Yeah, I am asking for curiosity, trying to understand the file system lol

Answer (score 2):

It appears so. Note that it applies to ScriptableObjects as well: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoScript.html?_ga=2.112551556.1460905390.1600095105-379318471.1582836001

Remember there are some other assemblies than just the one you mentioned, for example the "first pass" and "Editor" varieties. Also from Unity's documentation:

"A MonoBehaviour provides a wrapper that links to a MonoScript. A MonoScript is an internal data type that Unity uses to hold a reference to a specific scripting class within a specific assembly and namespace. The MonoScript does not contain any actual executable code."

This sounds very much like what you said. This excerpt may be found here: https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/assets-resources-and-assetbundles#5c7f8528edbc2a002053b5a6. You likely will need an account to access it.